# Why are my Modern UI desktop applications crashing?

Tags: windows-8, crash, modern-ui

For a while now a number of my desktop applications have been crashing within 1 minute of starting them up. They terminate with just a "X has closed" error. They include:

- Visual Studio
- Visual Studio installer, uninstaller, MSBUILD installer, etc
- Markdown Edit
- ChocolateyGUI
- Windows Photo Viewer (the one that is used to preview images, although this crashes with a COM error)

Other Modern UI applications with fullscreen (rather than desktop) interfaces like Reader (for PDFs) are fine.

Apart from Photo Viewer these all have what I recognise as Modern UI interfaces, which leads me to suspect a shared library is at fault.

I am running Windows 8.1 with all available updates installed. Why are these programs all crashing?

Comment: Any interesting errors in the Event Logs?

Comment: Stil valid in 8 & 8.1 is the SFC ./Scannow or /verify to check the integrity of the OS files.  (not yet valid for win10 which may show error always)  It is at least a start to run that as admin to check that aspect of the system.